# Is it possible to deploy Laravel 5.1 on server with PHP 5.5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5, web-deployment

One requirement for Laravel 5.1 is PHP >= 5.5.9, and the server I have now has PHP 5.5.0. Is it possible to deploy my laravel on it? I tried multiple ways but with no luck.

Things I have done/can do:

1. I tried add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php`
2. Tried to downgrade by change `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"` to `"laravel/framework": "5.0.*"` in composer.json under project root, then delete vendor folder, do `composer.json` but I got [image]

Any suggestions?

## update

Installed composer by:

1. Go to your php.ini file.
2. Locate the extension "extension=php_mbstring.dll".
3. Uncomment the extension, you do this by removing the semicolon in the same line.
4. Save your php.ini file.

Comment: The errors here are telling you that your server does not have `mbstring` enabled, so you should probably fix that.

Comment: why not? there are any errors messagens?

Comment: You can deploy but you can't run your application.